# One to many mapping. NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, one-to-many

I was looking at 'NHibernate 3 Beginner's Guide' book and found interesting tip:

> In a real life inventory application, you will probably want to avoid
>   putting a Products collection on the Category entity, as it is
>   possible that a category can have hundreds, if not thousands, of
>   associated products. To load the whole, huge collection of products
>   for a given category would be unwise and would lead to an application
>   having unsatisfactory response times.

Tip was right after an example of one-to-many relationships building. The entities were `Product` and `Category`. The example is quite straightforward:

```
public class Category : Entity // Entity probably contains an `Id` property
{
    private List<Products> products;

    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String Description  { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get { return products; } }
}  

public class Product : Entity
{
    public Decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

So what is the real life example of one-to-many relationships?

Would it be enough for the example just to put `Category` inside a product entity as a `String` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that if you avoid the IList property all-together, you can still get to the products for a category e.g. like the following:

```
var products = session.QueryOver<Product>().Where(p => p.Category == someCategory).List();
```

But you now have the possibility to do paging, filtering, getting the top product etc.:

```
var product = session.QueryOver<Product>().Where(p => p.Category == someCategory).OrderBy(p => p.Relevance).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

which you do not have if it is a simple IList property. In general (in my experience), the less two-way ascociations you have, the better your querying granularity will be. Also, it reduces your complexity when it comes to saving.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look a the lazy property of Nhibernate.It allows you  not to  load that property always unless we explicitly asks for it.

[Nhibernate Lazy](http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Let's ask different question: what if your application should present categories in **tree-view** control, which upon expanding category node will list all products? When you want to display all products there's no other way than ... actually querying database and loading all products.

That's actually pretty common real-life scenario and one of easiest approaches is indeed to simply have `Category.Products` property. Of course there's nothing wrong with having such property, but the real question is how you should manage those objects.

Luckily, you don't have to pull all the products with single category pull. `Category.Products` can be marked to *load lazily* (as opposed to *eagerly*, more information can be found [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/lazy-loading-eager-loading.aspx)). What this means is, loading category won't query database for its products. Instead, NHibernate will create *[proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object* for `Products`, which can be initialized later - when they are actually needed (think user expanding category node).

---

And to answer your question...

If single product is bound to *exactly one* category, then it's good real-life one-to-many relation example. However, if product can be described by more than one category, it's **many-to-many** relation then.

Answer (score -1):

I think the quote will say that you should not use the Products property in Category class at all.

Comment: There are many reasons to maintain a one-to-many property.  For example: if I have an order, I may choose to have an Items collection on that Order entity.  Since an order-item makes absolutely no sense outside the context of an order, I may even choose to not have a OrderItemRepository.